# React Router v4 - valid way to style Link component

Tags: reactjs, html, accessibility, react-router-v4

What is the most proper way to style `<Link>` component in React Router v4? If `<Link>` is simply an anchor tag, it shouldn't have `<button>` element nested inside. It also shouldn't be nested inside a button (because it doesn't make any sense), so the most valid way is to style it as a button. What are the cons of this approach?

Comment: Link tag does not by default has a nested button. It's indeed just an anchor tag. You can style it to make it look like a button if you want.

Comment: It is more of a HTML5 question. So the most valid way for HTML5 standards is to style `<Link>` to look like button as I mentioned in my question. What are cons of this approach? Maybe some a11y issues?

Comment: Sorry, can't help you there. It'd help to address this post to a different group maybe now that it's not exactly a react-router issue. You can also try attaching it with more relevant tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the `accessibility` tag was added, I'll answer from that perspective.

First decide if you want a link or a button.  A link is for navigational purposes.  It takes you to another page or somewhere else on the current page.  A button is for performing an action.

So you need to decide what should happen when the user selects the element.  Are you navigating (link) or performing an action (button)?

If you use a link and style it as a button because you want an action to happen, such as "add to cart" or "register" or "login", then there are several accessibility issues to handle:

- the [`role`](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.1/#role_definitions) of the link needs to be set to [`button`](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.1/#button)
- you need to add a keyboard handler to allow the <kbd>space</kbd> key to activate the link.  <kbd>enter</kbd> will already work but <kbd>space</kbd> is not a native action to a link.  When the role is set to "button", a screen reader will announce the element as a button and will tell the user to "press spacebar to activate", so you need to handle that key.

However, this could be resolved much easier if you just use a <button> instead of an <a>.  See the [first rule of ARIA](https://www.w3.org/TR/using-aria/#rule1).

Comment: That makes sense and I believe it should be correct answer. If I understand you correctly to perform navigation action I should just use React Router `<Link>` and style it. Is there any reason to use `<Link>` inside `<button>` element then?

Comment: I'm not a react expert.  I can only speak about accessibility. From a pure html perspective, a link (<a>) cannot have an embedded button (<button>) nor vice versa.  As far as styling, I would try to avoid making a link look like a button because then you'd be giving the wrong affordance, but otherwise style the link anyway you want as long as it looks like a link.